# How to retain A1 Notation in Excel fill after being dragged down for every row?

Tags: excel

How do I retain the value of **A1 Notation** after I drag it down to copy the formula to other rows?

For example, I have 2 columns, **A** and **B**, and let's say 10 rows, **1**-**10**

And the formula is =(A1)&"randomtexts"

I want the basic A1 notation (*I'm not sure what it's called, please let me know what*) and make it fixed in that formula so that it wont become A2, A3, A4, etc.. down the line?

I need it to be fixed A1, for this specific problem. Is there a word I can add to indicate it should always be A1 (or any specified cell) and not change it automatically?

Comment: You need to make the cell reference "Absolute" - try changing `=(A1)&"randomtexts"` to `=($A$1)&"randomtexts"` - you can make columns, rows or both absolute by putting the `$` sign in front of the column `$A1`, the row `A$1` or both `$A$1` - you can toggle through these too by pressing `F4` (try writing a formula `=A1` and then pressing `F4` a few times to see.

Comment: Thank you so much for the concise tutorial!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **$** like:

```
=A$1 & "whatever"
```

when copied downward the ***1*** will not advance to ***2***, ***3***, etc.

*(by the way, it is called "A1" notation)*

Comment: Thank you as well! What I really want to ask about the "A1" Notation is, what is it called when it's a formula? How can I reference that I'm talking about the formula which will insert A1 into a specified cell?